# Is there a stritcly objective difference between definitions and postulates?

Tags: logic, philosophy

I am reading the incredible Greenberg(2008, Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries)' book. I am not a mathematician. My doubt is the following: is there an objective difference between definitions and postulates? It seems to me that the difference is merely conventional, not strictly objective. Am I wrong? Please, I would like to know what mathematical-minded people think about that.

Comment: Postulates are more like axioms, although those are often _implicit_ definitions.

Comment: In general yes; a *definition* introduce a *new* term using previously known terms (or undefined basic ones). A postulate, like an axiom, states a property about some basic term.

Comment: See e.g [Set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation): the Empty set axiom is an axiom using the undefined relation $\in$, while the definition of $A \subseteq B$ introduce a new relation defined in terms of $\in$.

Comment: Very enlightening. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Already asked and answered [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92405/is-the-difference-between-definitions-and-postulates-merely-conventional).